# Does Around work in ListLogLinearPlot?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, around

I would like to create a plot with logarithmic x-axis, where the data has uncertainty in the x value. It's working fine with small negative y values, but when they're below `Log[$MinMachineNumber]`, it starts to sending messages like: `General::munfl="Exp[-1500.] is too small to represent as a normalized machine number; precision may be lost."` and messes up the plot:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[{{Around[10, 1], -1500}}]
```

[image]

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: A possible workaround is  `ListLogLinearPlot[ { {Around[10, 1], -1500} },
  PlotRange -> { {4, 20}, All } ] // Quiet`